# Sublime text 2 with LaTeXTools fails to compile (Windows)

Tags: windows, sublime-text

I work on Windows 7 X64 and since the latest update of LaTeXTools plugin for sublime text 2, the build (Ctrl+B) is failing with the following:

`[Compiling E:\Users\Seif\Desktop\1tsss\first.tex]`

`TraditionalBuilder: Invoking texify...`

And nothing is compiled!

I have followed the instructions to issue the command from the command palette "Reconfigure and migrate settings".

I'm using the default generated LaTeXTools.sublime-settings with the following:

```
"windows": {
    // Path to tex & friends. "" is fine for MiKTeX
    // For TeXlive 2013 (or other years) use
    // "texpath" : "C:\\texlive\\2013\\bin\\win32;$PATH",
    "texpath" : "",
    // TeX distro: "miktex" or "texlive"
    "distro" : "miktex"
},
```

The PATH variable contains both the path to MixText bin folder (E:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64) and the path to SumatraPDF (E:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF).

If I issue the same texify command plus the sumatrapdf from within the prompt command-line (cmd.exe) it works.

`E:\Users\Seif\Desktop\1tsss> texify -b -p --tex-option="--synctex=1" filename.tex && sumatrapdf filename.pdf`

I followed many threads searching for a solution but nothing succeeded in my case. A very similar question is [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/355) but all solutions there don't work. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! After a long search I figured out that the problem has been with a secondary language being set for Non-Unicode programs in the computer. To fix this just follow the steps:

`Control Panel -> Clock, Language & Region -> Region & Language -> Administrative -> Language for non-Unicode programs`

and set it from your old language to English using the `Change System Locale` button. Restart needed. Done!

Comment: I'm glad to see you could find a solution for your trouble. I use Sublime Text in Windows, gnu/linux and Mac and I never saw this before. Now I know what to do.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but do not have admin access on my machine (and thus cannot open said panel). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Surely to have many features to edit tex-files needed to do all the steps that you say, but for the compiler to work from within the editor is not needed so much work. Both step may discourage those (if not known) want to use it. Just go to:

```
 Tools -> Build System -> New Build System
```

and in the new tab that opens add:

```
{
"cmd": ["pdflatex", "$ file_name"]
"selector": "text.tex.latex"
}
```

and when you save choose as file name:

```
 latex.sublime-build
```

(keeping the directory configurations that the editor offers).

And without even restarting the Sublime Text compiling a tex-file with:

```
CTRL + B
```

Well I hope it will be useful.

Comment: Thank you Aradnix for your response. I performed your steps but the program compiles only once. The second time I press `ctrl+B` it gives an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File ".\makePDF.py", line 193, in run
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 949, in terminate
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied` and I must close it and open again to compile. Please any further help?

Comment: Are you the Admin in the windows machine where you use Sublime Text or are you only a common user? I searched about the error, but it seems [a python error] (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) [Take a look at this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395003/python-2-7-crashing-on-subprocess-py). Good luck.

Comment: Yes I'm Admin, but still having the error message below: `'texify', '-b', '-p', '--tex-option="--synctex=1"', 'first.tex'
('texify', '-b', '-p', '--tex-option="--synctex=1"', 'first.tex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File ".\makePDF.py", line 193, in run
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 949, in terminate
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`

Comment: I hope I can find a way out of this annoying problem

Comment: Uhm... Well, it's a lot of mistakes. I think it has more to do with how you installed Sublime Text and the packages you loaded and as you did, LaTeX Tools included instead of to do with LaTeX. My suggestion is to ask on forums or at the community of Sublime Text, you may find the answer there. Good Luck.

Comment: At last!! See my solution.

Comment: I don't forget to thank Aradnix for giving me the hope.